# URL check in JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am making a browser app for mobiles that takes URL and browse through it and it is working correctly. Now I want to perform a check on the text entered by the user before performing any action.

**First priority**: The URL check, whether it is in correct form or not.

**Second Priority**: If it is not a URL then it should go for a google search with the same keywords.

I did a validation on URL whether it is null or blank. But I want to perform above tasks that if it is not a URL, I will redirect it to Google search.

Can anyone help how to check the URL with JQuery Mobile?

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    document.addEventListener('deviceready',onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.notification.prompt(
            'Please enter the URL you want to browse', //massage
            onPrompt,   // callback to invoke
            'URL',      // title
            ['Ok','Exit']   //buttonLabels
        );
    }

    var ref=null;

    function onPrompt(results){
        if(results.input1==""||results.input1==null)
            onDeviceReady();
        else
            ref = window.open('http://'+results.input1, '_blank', 'location=yes');

        ref.addEventListener('loadstart', iLoadStart);
        ref.addEventListener('loadstop', iLoadStop);
        ref.addEventListener('loaderror', iLoadError);
        ref.addEventListener('exit', iLoadClose);
    }
</script>
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to test the contents of `results.input1`.

```
var urlregex = new RegExp("URL test regex");
if(urlregex.test(results.input1)) {
    // Go to URL
}
else
{
    // Google Search
}
```

(I'm a bit rusty on my Javascript, not sure this compiles)

And according to [this regex library](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL&c=2&m=5&ps=20), this is good URL regex:

```
(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

Comment: `var urlregex = new RegExp("(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?");
    function onPrompt(results){
     if(results.input1==""||results.input1==null){
      if(!urlregex.test(results.input1)) {
       onDeviceReady();
      }
     }else{
      ref = window.open('http://'+results.input1, '_blank', 'location=yes');
     } }
    ` I edited the code and made like this but the console is showing the error "Invalid regular expression". Sorry! I am not used to of regex, can you please check once?

Comment: Hmm, I haven't tested the regex before submitting, but it works according to [this tester](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx?regexp_id=96). Try removing the last part of the regex and adding it character by character. For a regex introduction, check [this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)